Finds the element in the array from which the elements in the array begin to be sorted in ascending order
We start with array of string, for example:
var strings = new List< string >()
{
    "qwerqwr",
    "asdfgsafsdf",
    "bsdfgsdf",
    "qweqweqwe",
    "casdcasdf",
    "adfasdfasdf",
    "bsadfgsadfsaf",
    "cdadadf",
    "eafdsf",
    "gasdfasdf"
};

We can see that array is sorted in ASC order from element at index 5 "adfasdfasdf".
Is there any "fast" possibility to find index of element where array starts to be sorted?

Well, you could process from the back end and break out as soon as a string sorts greater than the previous (i+1) string.

“Quick way”? Nope! Create an extension method with the logic and then it becomes quick.

Technically the array starts to be sorted at index 1.
